# PrimeFaces v3.5: Dialog is not shown using RequestContext on non-Ajax calls

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

In the User Guide, it is stated that `RequestContext` will work on both Ajax and non-Ajax calls. However, all of the examples in the User Guide are using Ajax and in my case, it doesn't work with non-Ajax calls.

The following is a test page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form >  

            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Non-Ajax" actionListener="#{mrBean.show}" />

            <p:commandButton value="Ajax" actionListener="#{mrBean.show}" />

        </h:form>

        <p:dialog modal="true" id="statusDialog" widgetVar="statusDlg" closable="false" >
            <h:outputText value="Helllooo" />
        </p:dialog>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And this is the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("SHOW DIALOG");
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.execute("statusDlg.show();");
    }

}
```

If I click the `Ajax` button, the dialog is shown correctly. However, the `Non-Ajax` button did nothing. In both case, the `SHOW DIALOG` message was printed on the console.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me how to tackle this problem :).

Best regards,

James Tran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must disappoint you, but `RequestContext` in non AJAX request is available but only useful function is `isAjaxRequest()` with boolean return value. In documentation and API reference you can see that for all other method it is told that they are for AJAX requests. Also for `execute()` method:

> Execute a javascript after current ajax request is completed.

At past, `RequestContext` wasn't available at all, now it is just available for possible future use with non AJAX requests. Additionally see [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?can=1&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary&sort=-id&id=4500)